# Display gridview cell values to textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row, editing

I'm working with asp.net nested gridview,in which I need to show the gridview cell values to the textbox for editing.

My problem is that I don't know how to display values to textbox if i ve used both template field & boundfield. Here is my aspx.

```
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10px">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png"  />
      <asp:Panel ID="pnsections" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Dept_Name") %>' />
      <asp:GridView ID="gvsections" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvsections_rowdatabound"  OnRowEditing="gvsections_rowediting"  DataKeyNames="Dept_Name">

      <Columns>

      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="currdept" HeaderText="Deptcurrent" />
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Dept_Name" HeaderText="SectionName" />
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FLDTYPE" HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-CssClass=" visible-lg visible-md" ItemStyle-CssClass=" visible-lg visible-md " />

      </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
   </asp:Panel>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Dept_Name" HeaderText="Department" />
 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FLDTYPE" HeaderText="Type" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: deptname.Text = gvdepts.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text showing empty value inside deptname textbox.

Comment: its a nested gridview and the parent gridview is 'gvdepts' , i ve a textbox named deptname.                                                                   deptname.Text = gvdepts.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text showing empty value inside deptname textbox.

Comment: try to modify your statement as follows **deptname.Text = (gvdepts.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0] as Label).Text**

Comment: @RameshBabu its showing the error i.e 'object reference  not set to an instance of an object.'  ??

Comment: Which gridview you want to edit the inner one or outer one?

Comment: try this deptname.Text = (gvdepts.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("HdnId") as HiddenField).Value // think that your hidden field contain dept name  as your code say.

Comment: its gvdepts parent gridview i want to edit. i want to hit onselectedindex changed property of gridview and display the cell values of selected row into different textbox in the form. Can't we do it without using hiddenfield @RojalinSahoo. thanks for your concern

Comment: did your inner grid contain more than one row?

Comment: @RojalinSahoo yes bro definitely, and i ve used hiddentfield control as u ve said,it worked but how can we do it on editing nested gridview rows?

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing the code in *selectedindexchanging* event of the grid view then try this and it will work

```
GridViewRow row = gvdepts.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
deptname.Text=row.Cells[1].Text;
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your code 3 fields contain dept name -- HdnId(Hiddenfield),inner gridview bound field (Dept_Name),Outer gridview bound field(Dept_Name).

```
1. deptname.Text = (gvdepts.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("HdnId") as HiddenField).Value; 

2. deptname.Text = (gvdepts.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("gvsections") as GridView).Rows[0].Cells[2].Text;

 3. deptname.Text = gvdepts.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
```

may this link solve your problem:
http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/133072/Edit-Update-Delete-in-Nested-Child-GridView-in-ASPNet/

Comment: in the given example,link button is used for editing but in my case, i want to edit without link buttons, through selected indexchanged property of the gridview. Whenever i click a row, selected indexchanged property should help to display gridcell values to the respective textbox of the form. I need help  in this.. thanks in advance .

Comment: using hiddenfield helped to display deptname value to the textbox but due to it,the child gridview vanished.

Comment: Fire onselectedindexchanged event. And get row index as:              row.Row Index == gridview.SelectedIndex and find required field